# What is the proper vim syntax highlighting for final, override keywords in c++?

Tags: vim, c++

In `~/.vim/syntax/c.vim`

I added:

```
syn keyword cStructure final override
```

because I didn't know what keyword type to use.

Any recommendations for the correct type for these function modifiers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not modify the default syntax script itself; you'll run into problems when updating Vim. Rather, put your additions into `~/.vim/after/syntax/c.vim`; this is sourced automatically after the default syntax.

Unless you plan to publish your extension or submit it as an enhancement to the original syntax's author, you can choose whatever pleases you. I would assign it to the `Keyword` group, which by default links to `Statement`.

```
:syn keyword cKeywords final override
:hi def link cKeywords Keyword
```

Comment: +1 tyvm - I didn't know about the `after` directory